# How can I send emails with my Angular app?

Tags: angular, email, backend

I have a question that I have been stuck on for weeks. I want to send an email after a registration on my website, with a thank you message for the registration and a registration confirmation with all the details.

While I know that Angular is a client and can't send emails, I unfortunately don't have a backend that can do that for me either. I am also unfortunately not a full stack web developer and lack the experience to do so.

Currently I host my Angular app with Firebase and do the registration there as well. Unfortunately, things don't look good for me with payment, which is why I can't pay for the email feature of Firebase. Is there any other option for me? Do I have to write a backend myself and host it with my own server? Unfortunately I don't have a server at home and I don't know exactly how to proceed to write an email function with backend.

If I can't get around it, what is the best recommendation for my approach?

I would appreciate any help you can give me!

With kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the volume of email that you need to send, and how fancy you want to get, you may be able to use a "paid" service with a free tier.

For instance, at the moment (Aug 2021), SendGrid has a free tier that offers basic functionality and 100 emails per day, and mailjet has a free tier that allows 200 emails per day.

Disclaimer - I have no association at all with either of the companies mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I will take that into consideration. I have done a lot of research on the net but have not found any tutorials on how to integrate Mailjet and SendGrid into my Angular app. Maybe I have to use normal HTML and JS after all, without great frameworks. I guess I have no other choice, but thanks for the help!